# Коррелят факультативен в следующих предложениях?

Tags: коррелят

1. Шутки шутили до тех пор, пока не начали прибывать свежие части.
2. В пойму реки Черевинки залетают мины и снаряды, словно куропатки стайками фыркают.
3. Так Феликс Боярчик нежданно-негаданно угодил в плен, хотя изо всей силы он хотел умереть.
4. Ум даден для того, чтобы облегчить жизнь и путь человеческий на земле.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В предложениях 2, 3 с союзами ХОТЯ и СЛОВНО коррелят невозможен.

В предложении 1 коррелят (предположительно) обязателен, так как сложный союз ДО ТЕХ ПОР ПОКА имеет не общее, а специализированное значение времени (указывает последовательность событий).

В предложении 4 коррелят факультативен, сложный союз ДЛЯ ТОГО ЧТОБЫ имеет книжный характер, дополнительной семантики он не содержит.